# Does reinstalling Mac OS X change the cycle count of battery?

Tags: macos, battery, system-information

If we go to System Information > Power in Apple menu, we see a parameter that is the cycle count of the battery. if we reinstall the operating system, will that remain the same or reset to 0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cycle count will remain as it is. This is read from the battery directly.

Like a car odometer, you shouldn't expect to be able to change the cycle count without replacing the battery. Being able to change the cycle count would be dishonest for the next person.

Comment: So, it's like it is hardwired into the battery! Thanks

Comment: Yes, just like hard drives, cd drives, USB interfaces, and every other piece of hardware that has to talk to your computer, batteries have firmware or drivers that give the operating system a standardized interface for communication with the battery. It does things like tracking charge level, cycles, and temperature, and controls charging, discharge, etc. It reports problems and status to the OS without letting it (or needing it) to interfere directly.

Comment: This effectively implies that the only way to reset the battery cycle count is to change the battery itself.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I think it implies the only way *should* be to change the battery itself.  Not clear to me if the only way *is* to change the battery itself, at least from this answer.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel You *might* be able to reflash the relevant part of the firmware on the battery storing the state, see e.g.. https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Miller/BH_US_11_Miller_Battery_Firmware_Public_WP.pdf.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel : Very interesting! +1